# How to Make Vlookup formula dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Could you help me with this line of code here please. I would like to make the Vlookup dynamic, where as

SalaryWage is the sheetname where the lookup has to be made, and normally, the table range is R33C1:R764C10. Each time a new row is added, so I would like to include it in the vlookup formula in an efficient way

Range("F4").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'SalaryWage'!R33C1:R964C10,10),0)"

Comment: Hi Rayan, maybe try introducing a new variable - like `dim lngLastRow as Long` and then calculate it as `lngLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` (as your table starts in column A). Afterwards you can adjust your formula as follows: `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'SalaryWage'!R33C1:R" & lngLastRow & "C10,10),0)"`  - hope it helps.

Comment: awesome :) P.S. For the future reference, I recommend also adding `excel` tag (currently `vba` and `vlookup` are being used) to increase your chances of a prompt response. Take care!